# pandas - two dateframes into one column

Tags: python, pandas

i have two dataframes

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3,4], 'B': [5,6,7,8], 'C': [9,10,11,12]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a','b','c','d'], 'B': ['e','f','g','h'], 'C': ['i','j','k','l']})
```

I am trying to combine the two dataframes but also add in the title of each column into a separate column. What i am looking to produce is below.

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'Serial': ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l'],
                'Cost': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12],
                'Name': ['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','C','C','C','C']})
```

I have tried iterating over the columns but ended up with a mess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way

```
In [33]: (pd.concat([df.unstack(), df2.unstack()], axis=1).reset_index()
           .drop('level_1', 1)
           .rename(columns={'level_0': 'Name', 0: 'Cost', 1: 'Serial'}))
Out[33]:
   Name  Cost Serial
0     A     1      a
1     A     2      b
2     A     3      c
3     A     4      d
4     B     5      e
5     B     6      f
6     B     7      g
7     B     8      h
8     C     9      i
9     C    10      j
10    C    11      k
11    C    12      l
```

Another way.

```
In [42]: pd.DataFrame({
            'Name': df.columns.repeat(len(df.index)), 
            'Cost': df.values.flatten(order='k'), 
            'Serial': df2.values.flatten(order='k')})
Out[42]:
    Cost Name Serial
0      1    A      a
1      2    A      b
2      3    A      c
3      4    A      d
4      5    B      e
5      6    B      f
6      7    B      g
7      8    B      h
8      9    C      i
9     10    C      j
10    11    C      k
11    12    C      l
```